# Update one field using the max value of another in a document

Tags: c#, mongodb

Boiled down to a MWE, I have a simple document in the following structure:

```
_id: ObjectId('deadbeefdeadbeefdeadbeef')
foo: 6
bar: 0
```

My goal is to update `bar` if and only if `foo` is greater, and if so, set it to `foo`.

My typical updates don't work, since the update definition is expecting a value:

```
_collection.UpdateMany(
    filter: document => true,
    update: Builders<MyDocument>.Update.Max(document => document.Bar, ___) // <-- I can't reference foo from here
);

// or

_collection.UpdateMany(
    filter: document => document.Bar < document.Foo
    update: Builders<MyDocument>.Update.Set(document => document.Bar, ___)
);
// System.ArgumentException: Unsupported filter: ({document}{bar} < {document}{foo})
```

The documentation on the C# driver (2.13.0) is frustratingly light, and I can't find many resources for C# regarding referencing a document's fields within an update.  What's the most elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The below chunk of code appears to do what I want, but this is fairly dirty and I'm not terribly satisfied with it.  Still, it's technically a possible solution:

```
_collection.UpdateMany(
    filter: "{ $expr: { $lt: [ '$bar', '$foo' ] } }", 
    update: PipelineDefinition<MyDocument, MyDocument>.Create("{ $set: { bar: '$foo' } }")
);
```

Having to craft queries out of JSON really isn't ideal when everything else can use my data models.  I have constants I can use, but I can't figure out how to do this with `Builders<T>`.  And especially once I build this out to my project which has far more complicated models, the JSON is going to be unwieldy.